# Proving the series of partial sums of $\sin (in)$ is bounded?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

So I'm trying to prove some series converges, and I'm trying to show it by using the Drichlet test.

So I need to prove that the series of partial sums $\Sigma_{k=1}^\infty \sin(ki)$ is bounded. I tried proving it by dividing and multiplying with $2\cos(\frac{i}{2})$ and then using the trigonometric identity $2\cos(\beta)\sin(\alpha)=sin(\alpha+\beta)-sin(\alpha-\beta)$, which creates a telescopic series - but I didn't manage to bound the result.

Any assistance would be great! Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is $i$ here? I suspect it's not imaginary unit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to obtain a bound is to derive a closed-from expression for the sum.  Here, this is accomplished by summing  geometric series. To that end,

$$\begin{align}
\left|\sum_{n=1}^N \sin(nx)\right| &=\left| \text{Im} \left(\sum_{n=1}^N e^{inx}  \right) \right|\\
&=\left|\text{Im} \left( \frac{e^{ix}-e^{i(N+1)x}}{1-e^{ix}} \right)\right| \\
&=\left|\frac{\sin \left(\frac{Nx}{2} \right) \sin\left(\frac{(N+1)x}{2}\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}\right|\\
&\le \left|\csc\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right|
\end{align}$$

Note:  A tighter bound can be obtained by noting 
$$\left|\sin \left(\frac{Nx}{2} \right) \sin\left(\frac{(N+1)x}{2}\right)\right|= \frac12 \left||\cos (\frac{x}{2})-\cos(N+\frac12)x \right|\le \frac12\left(1+\left|\cos (\frac{x}{2})\right|\right)$$

Answer (score 4):

I'll use $x$ in place of $i$ in order to avoid confusion with the imaginary number $\sqrt{-1}$. Also, I'll assume $x$ is not an integral multiple of $2\pi$.

Since

\begin{align}\sum_{k = 1}^n \sin(kx) &= \csc(x/2) \sum_{k = 1}^n \sin(kx)\sin(x/2)\\
& = \frac{1}{2}\csc(x/2) \sum_{k = 1}^n [\cos((k - 1/2)x) - \cos((k + 1/2)x)]\\
& = \frac{1}{2}\csc(x/2) [\cos(x/2) - \cos((n+1/2)x]
\end{align}

and the cosine is bounded by $1$,

$$\left|\sum_{k = 1}^n \sin(kx)\right| \le |\csc(x/2)|.$$

Since the upper bound is independent of $n$, the sequence of partial sums of $\sum_{k = 1}^\infty \sin(kx)$ is bounded.

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there. Since:

$$\begin{eqnarray*} 2\sin\frac{i}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{K}\sin(ki) &=& \sum_{k=1}^{K}\left(\cos\left(\left(k-\frac{1}{2}\right)i\right)-\cos\left(\left(k+\frac{1}{2}\right)i\right)\right)\\&=&\cos\frac{i}{2}-\cos\frac{(2K+1)i}{2}&\end{eqnarray*}$$

we have that for any $K$:
$$\left|\sum_{k=1}^{K}\sin(ki)\right|\leq\frac{\left|\cos\frac{i}{2}\right|+1}{2\left|\sin\frac{i}{2}\right|}$$
This bound is optimal since for any $\varepsilon > 0$ we can find a $K\in\mathbb{N}$ such that the difference between the LHS and the RHS of the last line is less than $\varepsilon$.

Comment: It is correct, also checked with WA. It is just a stronger inequality than yours, since you have bounded $\left|\cos\frac{i}{2}\right|$ with one, but there is no need of doing that.

Comment: Well, I didn't enforce that particular bound explicitly, but implicitly only.  Rather, I enforced $|sin(Nx/2)sin((N+1)x/2)|\le1$.  Of course, the term under the absolute value can be written $\frac{1}{2}|\cos(x/2)-\cos((N+1/2)x)|$.  So, I bounded this entire expression by $1$ by tacitly bounding both terms under the absolute value by $1$.

Comment: I tried a numerical check.  Suppose $K=1$ and $i=5$.  Then $|\sin(5)| \approx 0.95892$ while $\frac12 \cot(5/4)| \approx 0.1661$.  I believe that the problem is with the last step in which you applied an identity by removing absolute values and then reapplying them thereafter.

Comment: @Dr.MV: ok, you're right. Fixed by just removing the very last piece.

Comment: You're a very creative mathematician and I always appreciate reading your solutions.  Just glad I could help for once!