# Is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\sin(nx)$ converges on $[\varepsilon, 2\pi-\varepsilon]$?

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, summation, uniform-convergence, fake-proofs

> Let $a_n$, a sequence monotonically decreasing to $0$. Consider
>
> $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\sin(nx)$$
>
> Is the series converges uniformly on $[\varepsilon, 2\pi-\varepsilon]$?
>   ($\varepsilon > 0$)

Basically we could use Dirichlet's test. We want to show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin (nx)$ is bounded. Indeed:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin (nx) = \frac{i}{2}\left( \sum_{n=1}^\infty (e^{ix})^n + \sum_{n=1}^\infty (e^{-ix})^n\right) \le \frac{i}{2} \left( \frac{1}{1-e^{ix}} +\frac{1}{1-e^{-ix}} \right) \le \frac{1}{1-e^{i(2\pi-\varepsilon)}} <\infty$$

BUT, clearly, $$g(\frac{\pi}{2}) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin \frac{n\pi}{2} = \infty$$

Where is the mistake?

Comment: Actually g(pi/2) is perfectly bounded between -1 and 1...

Comment: @Chilango in fact it can only be 0,1

Comment: @Vim: Yes thanks!

Comment: I know you know this, but complex numbers dont have an order.

Comment: Thank you all. By the way, why is the last inequality even holds?

Comment: @Nameless, it would be better if I used absolute value then?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "then". Anyways, your last series is alternating and divergent.

Comment: Is there a differecen between convergence on $[\varepsilon, 2\pi - \varepsilon]$ for $\varepsilon > 0$ and $(\varepsilon, 2\pi)$?

Comment: $\sin(n\pi/2) = 1, 0, -1, 0, ...$ so its sum is bounded.

Answer (score 3):

We show that if $a_n$ is monotonically decreasing, then the series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n\sin (nx)$$

is uniformly convergent on $[\epsilon,2\pi-\epsilon]$, for any fixed $\epsilon>0$.

To test the uniform convergence we use [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1206631/proving-the-series-of-partial-sums-of-sin-in-is-bounded/1206665#1206665) in which I showed that

$$\begin{align}
\left|\sum_{n=1}^N \sin(nx)\right| \le \frac12\left(1+\left|\cos (\frac{x}{2})\right|\right)\left|\csc\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right|
\end{align}$$

Now, for any fixed $\epsilon$, we have for $x\in [\epsilon,2\pi-\epsilon]$,

$$\begin{align}
\left|\sum_{n=1}^N \sin(nx)\right| &\le \frac12\left(1+\left|\cos (\frac{x}{2})\right|\right)\left|\csc\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right|\\\\
&\le \csc(\epsilon/2) \tag 1
\end{align}$$

For the Dirichlet test of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n\sin (nx)$, we only require the following two conditions:

**Condition $(1)$**

The sequence $a_n$ decreases monotonically to zero.

**Condition $(2)$**

The partial sums $\sum_{n=1}^N  \sin(nx)$ be bounded by a constant.

Condition $(1)$ is presumed while equation $(1)$ confirms Condition $(2)$.

Thus, if $a_n$ is monotonically decreasing, then for $x\in [\epsilon, 2\pi-\epsilon]$, for any fixed $\epsilon >0$, we have that

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n\sin (nx)\,\,\text{converges uniformly}}$$

---

As a side note, we have that the series $\sum_{n=1}^N \sin x \sin(nx)$ converges for $x\in [0,2\pi]$

We have

$$\begin{align}
\left|\sum_{n=1}^N \sin x \sin(nx)\right| &\le \frac12\left(1+\left|\cos (\frac{x}{2})\right|\right)\left|\sin x\csc\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right|\\\\
&=\left(1+\left|\cos (\frac{x}{2})\right|\right)\left|\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right|\\\\
&\le2 \tag 2
\end{align}$$

For the Dirichlet test of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n\sin (x)\sin (nx)$, we only require the following two conditions:

**Condition $(1)$**

The sequence $a_n$ decreases monotonically to zero.

**Condition $(2)$**

The partial sums $\sum_{n=1}^N \sin (x) \sin(nx)$ be bounded by a constant.

Condition $(1)$ is presumed while equation $(2)$ confirms Condition $(2)$.

and we are done!

Comment: I am gonna have to favorite this question because of that box...

Comment: @Nameless Now that was funny!

Answer (score 2):

You last "clearly" is problematic. Because $g(\pi/2)$ is bounded between 0 to 1.