# Proving $\sum \limits _{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin (n)}{n}$ convergent

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I need to prove that  $\sum \limits _{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin (n)}{n}$ convergent ***only by Cauchy's test***.

***Cauchy's test for sequences convergence*** :

The $\sum \limits _{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ convergent $\iff$ $\forall \varepsilon >0$ $ \exists$ $ n_0\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall $ $n_0 \le n$ , $\forall$ $p\in \mathbb{N}$ the following holds $\mid S_{n+p}-S_n\mid = \mid a_{n+1}+\dots+a_{n+p}\mid<\varepsilon$

---

***My Attempt:***

Let $\varepsilon>0$,$\ p\in\mathbb{N}$. We define $n_0=\frac{p}{\varepsilon}$, and since $-1\le \sin(x)\le 1$ therefore, for each $n\le n_0$: $$\mid \frac{\sin (n+1)}{n+1}+\frac{\sin (n+2)}{n+2}+...+\frac{\sin (n+p)}{n+p} \mid \ \le \ \mid \frac{\sin (n+1)}{n+1}\mid + \mid \frac{\sin (n+2)}{n+2}\mid+...+\mid \frac{\sin (n+p)}{n+p} \mid \le \frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+...+\frac{1}{n+p}\le \frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n}+...+\frac{1}{n}=\frac{p}{n}<\varepsilon$$

Is my proof correct? if not so how can I prove it ***only by Cauchy's test*** as I said earlier, ***without*** any further test - such as Dirichlet, Abel...

Comment: Your proof *cannot* be correct: It would imply that the harmonic series is convergent.

Comment: @MartinR Yes, this is the reason I was wondering...

Comment: $|S_{n+p}-S_n| < \epsilon$ must hold for all $n \ge n_0$ and all $p$, you cannot define $n_0$ depending on $p$.

Comment: @MartinR Oh I see. How can I prove the convergence of the sequence, but by Cauchy's test?

Comment: Try applying summation by parts first.

Comment: @MarkViola I have tried, without any success. I will be happy to see your thoughts in an answer.

Comment: Are you familiar with summation by parts?

Comment: @MarkViola In what context? and I have to prove that only by Cauchy's test.

Comment: I suggest you research summation by parts and try again.

Comment: @MarkViola Is it a move that can help my proving this by Cauchy's test? and I cannot use other tests, I said that in my question. I need a pure proof using Cauchy's test...

Comment: Of course you can use Cauchy's criterion.

Comment: @MarkViola Can you show me how? because every step I want to make there is something that blocks me to proceed. I need to prove it with pure Cauchy's test proof, without any other tests, but an algebra manipulation, or something alike.

Comment: @MarkViola "Of course you can use Cauchy's criterion" I also tried without success.
it will be nicely if you show how .

Comment: @ATB I've posted a solution per your request.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**There have been a couple of requests in the comments to show a way forward after I suggested applying summation by parts.  To that end, we proceed.**

---

Since we asked to prove that the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(n)}{n}$ converges, we begin with the partial sum $S_N$ defined by

$$S_N=\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\sin(n)}{n}$$

Letting $T_n=\sum_{m=1}^n \sin(m)$ and summing by parts, we have for $N>M+1$

$$\begin{align}
\left|S_N-S_M\right|&=\left|\frac{T_N}{N+1}-\frac{T_M}{M+1}+\sum_{n=M+1}^N \left(\frac1n-\frac1{n+1}\right)T_n\right|\\\\
&\le \max_n (|T_n|)\left(\frac1{N+1}+\frac1{M+1}+\frac1{M+1}-\frac1{N+1}\right)
\end{align}$$

I showed in [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1206631/proving-the-series-of-partial-sums-of-sin-in-is-bounded) that $\max_n |T_n|\le \frac12(\csc(1/2)+\cot(1/2))\le 2$.

Using this bound for $|T_n|$, we can assert that for any given $\varepsilon >0$, $|S_N-S_M|<\varepsilon$ whenever $N>M+1>\frac{4}{\varepsilon}$.

From Cauchy's criterion, we conclude that $S_N$ converges.  And we are done!

Comment: First of all , Thanks a lot for your solution , by the way I hardly can understand the $|S_N-S_M| = |\frac{\sin(N)}{N+1}-....$ this line . how you get it from the line before I will appreciate that if you will explain in a few words that will make me understand each line in the proof.
I think that in the same line I asked you for .. the $|S_N-S_M| = |\frac{\sin(N)}{N+1}-....$ not should be $|S_N-S_M| = |\frac{\sin(N)}{N}-\frac{\sin(M+1)}{M+1}... ?$

Comment: @ATB You're welcome.  My pleasure.  Please review summation by parts to gain an understanding of the posted solution.  While it's possible that there is an error in the bookkeeping, I believe all is correct as is.  When I have more time, I'll review and revert.  Otherwise, try going through application of summation by parts on your own and see if you can verify the details.

Comment: @ATB There was a bookkeeping error, which I've edited.

Comment: I think the author of this question in this post mean that you solve without Abel's theorem or Abel transformation, just only by the Cauchy's criterion.

Comment: @ATB Summation by parts is not anything unusual.  It's just arithmetic.  So, I don't believe that the OP meant that one is prohibited from using any arithmetic whatsoever.  And inasmuch as the OP accepted the answer, your supposition is rather dubious at best.

Comment: I have accepted your answer because it seems to be right, however after thinking, I don't think I have learned the method you have used in your answer - "summation by parts". How can I show it by easy algebra moves? I will be happy to see how you will prove it with only algebra. Moreover, the inequality of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin(n) \le \frac{2}{5}$, I don't think I have learned that either, or proved... is there an alternative for your answer? - but of course with my conditions mentioned in my question, if so, it will be great if you can add it to your answer. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Johan.  [HERE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts#Method) is a link which discusses summation by parts.  It is analogous to integration by parts, which you have likely learned.  I added a link to an answer I posted that provides an upper bound estimate for $\left|\sum_{m=1}^n \sin(m)\right|$.  In fact, it is bounded by $2$.

Comment: It is so complicated for me, because I am a beginner with the sequences topic. Can you show it in the easiest way by Cauchy? because summation by parts and the bounded limit of $| T_n |$ I am not allowed to use.

Comment: Johan, if you understand the proof of Cauchy's criterion, and understand integration by parts, then surely summation by parts and the way I developed a bound for $|T_n|$ are well within your grasp.  I don't know a simpler way to prove convergence of $S_n$

Answer (score -3):

Your proof is wrong because you have
$\sin(n)$ in the numerators
where you should have
$\sin(n+p)$.

Comment: The proof would still be wrong if $\sin(n)$ is replaced by $\sin(n+p)$, where appropriate.

Comment: Then, how can I show it by Cauchy's test? this is the main purpose of the question...

Comment: Sorry, apparently I have done that in my proof, but forgot to change it. It has fixed.