# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(n)}{n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I need to prove the convergence of: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(n)}{n}$.

To do it I wanted to use the [alternating series test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test). I know that $a_n=1/n\overset{n\rightarrow \infty }{\rightarrow} 0$ but for example $\sin(1)>0$ and $\sin(2)>0$ so I can't use it directly. What should I do?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4073653/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4084055/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2227574/42969 – these (and more) can be found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bn%3D1%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%20%7D%5Cfrac%7B%5Csin(n)%7D%7Bn%7D%24)

Comment: Welcome to the Math Stack Exchange.  For future questions please be courteous and spell check your questions before posting to the site.  Thank you.

Comment: The alternating series test is a special case of [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test). Try using Dirichlet's test instead.

Comment: Thank you for your help

Comment: See also my answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4084102/399263 where I show a way to prove it directly (well in fact it is kind of the Dirichlet test, but with a shortcut for this particular case).